# pre-receive hook - how to get messages of commits

Tags: git, githooks

How to get messages of commits that are received by server in pre-receive hook using bash?

I've tried to print:

```
echo >&2 $1 $2 $3
```

but only I get:

```
remote: 62e1ce5353f74f21eafac129dcff0074b2cc7a19 f58a366385ba105ecv1e2f3fbfe99ca60be737c72 refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember you get the old hash, the new hash and the ref that is pushed. So just use git-log to get what you want.

Just the subject lines: `git log --format="%s" $1..$2`
Just the body lines: `git log --format="%b" $1..$2`
Subject and body lines: `git log --format="%B" $1..$2`

For more format options, read the man page of `git log`

Comment: Thank you very much. It did work. Although all messages are printed in one line, and I want to validate them separately, I made little trick using %f, it gives us instead of spaces '-'. So now spaces can be delimiter between commits. it is helpful till it does not matter that someone used '-' actually, or not. Anyway, can validate for empty messages and 'fix' only messages now, so yea, works brilliant :)

Comment: It's worth pointing out, I think, that this same technique (but with many more features) is used in the `post-receive-email` hook included with git (found in `.../contrib/hooks/post-receive-email` where the `...` part varies depending on configuration).  See `generate_update_branch_email` for the typical update path, and note all the other special cases handled elsewhere, for branch and tag creation and so forth.